# Hadoop Hue: Counter results greyed out

Tags: hadoop, solr, hue

I have created a Solr dashboard with analytics enabled. The Counter button is now shown, but its greyed out. Is there any additional flag in Hue or solr which I should enable?

Thanks

I am using Solr 7 + Hue 4

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-7337 that will be fixed soon. A workaround is to add a numeric field in your collection.